# Where to find Payment Log file?

Tags: orders, sales-order, magento2.2.3

When we check the Sales Order in Magento, some of the order numbers are missing randomly. I have tried to find the Payment Log file to check what happened to the missing orders but I couldn't able to find the Payment Log file.

Could anyone please tell me where I can find the Payment Log file in Magento?

**Magento Version: 2.2.3**